# How do you transfer parameters from the router to the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do you transfer parameters from the router to the component?...
It appears twice in the console log.
First, signin, second, signout.
I don't know why it comes out twice, I'm accurately distinguishing passes by "exact ", but I don't know why signout appears in the console log when I typed url   `http://localhost:8080/signin`.

app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import * as Pages from "./pages";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Pages.home} />
          <Route
            exact
            path={config.url.pathName}
            component={Pages.auth(config.url.text)}
          />
          <Route exact path="/signout" component={Pages.auth("signout")} />
          <Route component={Pages.notfound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
page/auth.js
import React from "react";
import { page as Page } from "pages";
import { AuthContainer } from "containers";

function auth(type) {
  **console.log("page auth", type);** <- page auth signin and page auth signout twice console.log!
  return (
    <>
      <Page title={"login"} />
      <AuthContainer type={type} />
    </>
  );
}

export default auth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your calling the Pages.auth function when rendering App. You should pass a component rather than call it. The log is showing twice because you have called the function twice in app.js. To achieve what you're after you can use the `useLocation` hook to get the route you're on.

See https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation for more info on `useLocation`.

```
app.js
import React from "react";
import * as Pages from "./pages";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Pages.home} />
          <Route
            exact
            path={config.url.pathName}
            component={Pages.auth}
          />
          <Route exact path="/signout" component={Pages.auth} />
          <Route component={Pages.notfound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

page/auth.js
import React from "react";
import { page as Page } from "pages";
import { AuthContainer } from "containers";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function auth() {
  let location = useLocation();
  console.log("location: ", location);

  return (
    <>
      <Page title={"login"} />
      <AuthContainer type={type} />
    </>
  );
}

export default auth;
```